# Using Twilio, unable to recieve real sms on phone using Trial Account in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sms, twilio, sms-gateway, twilio-api

My code for sending the sms in **Node.js**

```
var accountSid = ''; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
var authToken = '';   // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console


// Load the twilio module
var twilio = require('twilio');

// Create a new REST API client to make authenticated requests against the
// twilio back end
var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

// Pass in parameters to the REST API using an object literal notation. The
// REST client will handle authentication and response serialzation for you.
client.messages.create({
    to: 'my_number',  // verified
    from: '+15005550006', // From a valid Twilio number
    body:'ahoy hoy! Testing Twilio and node.js'
}, function(error, message) {
    // The HTTP request to Twilio will run asynchronously. This callback
    // function will be called when a response is received from Twilio
    // The "error" variable will contain error information, if any.
    // If the request was successful, this value will be "falsy"
    if (!error) {
        // The second argument to the callback will contain the information
        // sent back by Twilio for the request. In this case, it is the
        // information about the text messsage you just sent:
        console.log('Success! The SID for this SMS message is:');
        console.log(message.sid);

        console.log('Message sent on:');
        console.log(message.dateCreated);
    } else {
        console.log('Oops! There was an error.');
         console.log(error)
    }
});
```

Everything Works Fine but I didn't get the **Actual/Real SMS** so how would I confirmed by only seeing the success result on console.That's why I want to get the **Actual/Real SMS** not only just success message in console ?

So there is no provision to get actual message using **Trial Account**.

Any suggestions, recommendations or answers would be more helpfule to me
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using your live or test credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a trial account?

If so you need to add the number of the phone you want to call as a verified number. You can do that [Here](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified).

Comment: My number is already added their. But unable to send real sms and I don't try for voice call. After sending sms, then I will try to do that too